# Swift for Linux: no such module 'Python'

Tags: python, linux, swift, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to call a Python function from an executable written in Swift.

There's a convenient library to do this, I have to `import Python` in swift and use the appropriate function. This was built successfully on mac, but on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04), I get an error when I try to build :

> error: no such module 'Python' import Python

I'm running tests with Ubuntu running on a virtual machine (with Virtual Box from a mac host). The executable I'm building is intended to run on a server.

Python 2.7 is running on all machines.

Comment: Can you run straight Python code on the server?

Comment: where in the question does it say a server is involved? @KeithJohnHutchison

Comment: It doesn't ... I assumed it was a server. Can you run straight Python code on the Ubuntu device?

Comment: Yes I can. I'm running tests with Ubuntu running on a virtual machine (with Virtual Box from a mac host).
The executable I'm building is intended to run on a server though.
For reference, It's running Python 2.7.12

Comment: The `Python.framework` imported via `import Python` is only available on the Mac. I suppose you should follow the "Unix-like system" suggestion in "Embedding the Python Framework" here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2328/_index.html (linking to the headers instead of importing)

Comment: What does the function written in python do ... can you park it out as a separate process?